# Why does `time.sleep()` raise an `IOError` beyond 100000000?

Tags: python

I'm using `python 2.7.10` on a 64-bit Mac OS X machine. Why does `time.sleep()` raise an `IOError` beyond 100000000?

In the example below, `time.sleep(100000000)` works, but `time.sleep(100000001)` raises `IOError`

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(100000000)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
>>>
>>> time.sleep(100000001)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: What sort of program would need to sleep for over 3 years anyway?

Comment: This isn't production code. I'm simply curious.

Comment: My bet is since these numbers have to be held in some memory slot with finite size at run time, there's got to be an upper bound. They went for 100,000,000s which seems more than enough for any practical case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is specific to macOS, not to Python. [Python uses the `select()` function to implement `sleep`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1426daa4fe47d8f8be0d416f7cba7adae1d5839f/Modules/timemodule.c#L1762), and Perl exhibits the same behavior on macOS if you try to run `select` with a timeout of over 1e8 seconds:

```
# perl -E 'select $x, $x, $x, 100000001; say $!'
Invalid argument
```

The [`itimerfix`](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/kern/kern_time.c#L601) function in the XNU kernel looks like a likely culprit for this behavior:

```c
/*
 * Check that a proposed value to load into the .it_value or
 * .it_interval part of an interval timer is acceptable.
 */
int
itimerfix(
    struct timeval *tv)
{

    if (tv->tv_sec < 0 || tv->tv_sec > 100000000 ||
        tv->tv_usec < 0 || tv->tv_usec >= 1000000)
        return (EINVAL);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of this reply, great job!